# What namespace should I use for an XML schema?

Tags: xml, xsd, tags, uri

I'm developing a custom XML schema for communicating data between application components.  What do the SO folks consider a good (or, ideally, *best*) practice for selecting the URI for the namespace?  Why?

Some basic consideration:

Our product has many components, and it's probably a good idea if the namespace indicates which component will be consuming it.  Beyond that, there's specific types of data.  How qualified should I go?

Our business unit has changed ownership a few times, and is likely to do so again.  Keeping the company name in the URI is a bit weird, when that happens, but it's not out of the question.  Is leaving this in a good idea?

HTTP urls are nice, but we've never had a web server up to get these schema, so divorcing that makes a fair amount of sense.  Nonetheless, it seems to be a convention.  Is it worth following?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is mostly a matter of taste. Some requirments are not easily compatible (such as resolvability and long-term stability), so try to find out what is most important to you. Nevertheless, a few opinions:

1. I find it better to have the namespace URI resolve to an actual Web page (for documentation and so on) so it is worth using a "good" (stable, beautiful) domain name.
2. If you want long-term stability, in presence of name changes and so on, the most lightweight solution, which does not require yet another registry, is the tag URI, standardized in [RFC 4151](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4151.txt). Just keep in mind they are not resolvable.